# join 2 genealogy trees on 2 different points

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, genealogytree

The following LaTeX document contains two genealogy trees joined on `Matilde Oltre`. Now I would like to join `Vittorio Moletti` with `Modesta Oltre` (Matilde's sister) as a couple, having `Rina Moletti` and `Santa Moletti` as their daughters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500mm,paperheight=500mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
    %   \section{First Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@main_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}
                p[female]{Santa Moletti}
                
                
                child
                {
                    g[female]{Lucia Moletti}
                    c[female]{Carla Parenti}
                }
                c[male]{Felicetto Moletti}
                child
                {
                    g[male]{Vittorio Moletti}
                    c[female]{Santa Moletti}
                    c[female]{Rina Moletti}
                }
                child
                {
                    g[male]{Romoluccio Moletti}
                    p[female, id=matilde_oltre]{Matilde Oltre}
                    child
                    {
                        g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}                        
                    }
                    child
                    {
                        g[female]{Luciana Moletti}                      
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@oltre_tree, set position=matilde_oltre@oltre_tree at matilde_oltre@main_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Felice Oltre}
                p[female]{Lucrezia Endemore}
                child
                {
                    g[female, id=matilde_oltre]{Matilde Oltre}
                }
                child
                {
                    g[female]{Modesta Oltre}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: original tree]

To achieve that I tried

```
$ diff -urNr albero_genealogico_stackoverflow.tex albero_genealogico_stackoverflow_2.tex 
--- albero_genealogico_stackoverflow.tex      2022-12-28 19:07:01.493305752 +0100
+++ albero_genealogico_stackoverflow_2.tex    2022-12-28 19:09:53.124633376 +0100
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
                                child
                                {
                                        g[male]{Vittorio Moletti}
+                                       p[female, id=modesta_oltre]{Modesta Oltre}
                                        c[female]{Santa Moletti}
                                        c[female]{Rina Moletti}
                                }
@@ -40,7 +41,7 @@
                        }
 
                }
-               \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@oltre_tree, set position=matilde_oltre@oltre_tree at matilde_oltre@main_tree]
+               \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@oltre_tree, set position=matilde_oltre@oltre_tree at matilde_oltre@main_tree, set position=modesta_oltre@oltre_tree at modesta_oltre@main_tree]
                {
                        child
                        {
@@ -52,7 +53,7 @@
                                }
                                child
                                {
-                                       g[female]{Modesta Oltre}
+                                       g[female, id=modesta_oltre]{Modesta Oltre}
                                }
                        }
                }
```

but I got a huge overlapping

[image: overlapping trees]

**Full LaTeX code of such attempt**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500mm,paperheight=500mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
    %   \section{First Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@main_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}
                p[female]{Santa Moletti}
                
                
                child
                {
                    g[female]{Lucia Moletti}
                    c[female]{Carla Parenti}
                }
                c[male]{Felicetto Moletti}
                child
                {
                    g[male]{Vittorio Moletti}
                    p[female, id=modesta_oltre]{Modesta Oltre}
                    c[female]{Santa Moletti}
                    c[female]{Rina Moletti}
                }
                child
                {
                    g[male]{Romoluccio Moletti}
                    p[female, id=matilde_oltre]{Matilde Oltre}
                    child
                    {
                        g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}                        
                    }
                    child
                    {
                        g[female]{Luciana Moletti}                      
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@oltre_tree, set position=matilde_oltre@oltre_tree at matilde_oltre@main_tree, set position=modesta_oltre@oltre_tree at modesta_oltre@main_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Felice Oltre}
                p[female]{Lucrezia Endemore}
                child
                {
                    g[female, id=matilde_oltre]{Matilde Oltre}
                }
                child
                {
                    g[female, id=modesta_oltre]{Modesta Oltre}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can you please help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to give an include the children of each couple in the `@oltre_tree` and give an `id` to the parent remaining in the `@main_tree`. Then, you only need to `add parent= id_person to id_family` and finally, you can position Matilde Oltre next to Romoduccio Moletti `adjust node= id_person right/left of id_person distance xx cm`.

I also shifted the edges of the concerned families up and down so they can be differenciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500mm,paperheight=500mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
    %   \section{First Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@main_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}
                p[female]{Santa Moletti}
                
                
                child
                {
                    g[female]{Lucia Moletti}
                    c[female]{Carla Parenti}
                }
                c[male]{Felicetto Moletti}
                c[male, id=Vittorio_Moletti]{Vittorio Moletti}
                c[male, id=Romoluccio_Moletti]{Romoluccio Moletti}
            }
            
        }
        \genealogytree[template=signpost,id suffix=@oltre_tree, adjust node=matilde_oltre@oltre_tree right of Romoluccio_Moletti@main_tree distance 0.2cm, add parent= Romoluccio_Moletti@main_tree to fam_Matilde_Oltre@oltre_tree, add parent=Vittorio_Moletti@main_tree to fam_Modesta_Oltre@oltre_tree]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{Felice Oltre}
                p[female]{Lucrezia Endemore}
                child[id=fam_Matilde_Oltre, edges up by=1 of 6]
                {
                    g[female, id=matilde_oltre]{Matilde Oltre}
                    child
                    {
                        g[male]{Arnaldo Moletti}                        
                    }
                    child
                    {
                        g[female]{Luciana Moletti}                      
                    }
                }
                child[id=fam_Modesta_Oltre, edges down by= 1 of 6]
                {
                    g[female]{Modesta Oltre}
                    c[female]{Santa Moletti}
                    c[female]{Rina Moletti}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]